# Javascript doesn't redirect immediately after response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi I'm trying to do a redirect if a response from an ajax request is receive. But somehow the **windows.href.location** doesn't redirect until the PHP background process completes in processing. Below is my code

```
 // The php script that run the background process
<?php 
    $background = new BackgroundProcess('email.php');
    $background->run(); // The background process is running now
    return $background->getPid(); // This returns immediately to the frontend
?>
```

And this is my ajax request using jquery

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/payment',
    data:form.serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(txt){
        if (txt.response == "ok"){
            console.log("done redirecting now");
            window.location.href = "/confirmation";
        }else{
            alert("failed process");
        }
    },
    type: 'POST'
});
```

Now the **done redirecting now** prints on the console. Meaning a response was received. But I'm expecting to execute the next line which is the **windows.href** but this is not executed until the background process in my php script is done. Any idea on how to solve this?

Note: The PHP process is running as expected its just that the javascript redirect doesn't redirect immediately and is waiting for the php script to finish

Comment: Given that that code executes in the callback, the PHP script *must* have completed and sent the response for the `success` handler function to be invoked. It seems more likely that there is simply a delay in the new page loading, rather than some odd behaviour resulting from the AJAX request.

Comment: That's what I thought previously but as soon as all the background process is done with the process that is when the redirect takes effect. I'm running a 100 email sending for this process and I'm recording the progress in my db. So upon completing the process in the db that is when the page is redirecting

Comment: Possibly a server load issue if that process is really intensive

Comment: `So upon completing the process in the db that is when the page is redirecting` That sounds like correct behaviour. What exactly are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Is the background process messing with the session?

Comment: @KevinB I don't think so. Since what its doing is just to retrieve records from the db and send an email. All it contains is an initialization of db connection and processing of records

Comment: because, what it sounds like to me is the background process is preventing php from processing the request made by the redirect, which is commonly caused by working with the session. I'm not sure what else could cause this problem, as Ianaphpd

Comment: Try removing the process temporarily. If you see a big speed boost  do some profiling of it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm running a background process in my script so I thought that background process should not interfere with the redirection

Answer (score -1):

Assigning to `window.location.href` doesn't cause an immediate redirect, the effect is only seen when Javascript returns to the main event loop. This allows you to do additional processing before the redirect, including reassigning the location to change where you're redirecting to. E.g.

```
window.location.href = "/page1";
window.location.href = "/page2";
```

will redirect to `/page2`, because this overrides the earlier assignment.

Comment: I just tested it, and it tried to redirect to the second URL. What about it doesn't work?

Comment: sorry maybe I didn't made my question quite clear. I'm testing the redirection after an ajax call. This ajax call to a php script triggers a background process. After returning a response it doesn't redirect immediately and it had to wait for the background process to finish to continue its redirection.

Comment: But you're seeing the console log before the background process finishes? I can't think of any way that can happen. Once the AJAX request returns, the browser doesn't know anything about what's happening on the server.